# MySQL ошибка запуска

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? на локальном сервере отвалилась БД и не запускается, порт менял.

```
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk 
size = 16M
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47055; transaction id 9
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200818 10:17:14
2020-08-18 10:17:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Также сталкивался с этой проблемой, решение нашлось здесь.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412698/xampp-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-dont-work

Comment: @TommyHumble Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Решение было взято из комментария @Tommy Humble, из папки C:\xampp\mysql\backup вам необходимо скопировать все данные и вставить в папку C:\xampp\mysql\data в папке data могут быть еще куча разных файлов , ничего там удалять не надо, просто копируем и выбираем заменить при копировании, у меня все заработало. Но при этом если попытаться открыть таблицу #1932 - Table doesn't exist in engine.